# How to encrypt an 8TB disk with Veracrypt with hidden partition?

Tags: linux-mint, large-files, veracrypt

When I try to encrypt an USB 8tb drive (Seagate Expansion Drive) with Veracrypt to create a Hidden Veracrypt volume, I receive this error:

> Error: The hidden volume to be created is larger than 2 TB (2048 GB).
>
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Create a container/partition smaller than 2 TB.
> - Use a drive with 4096-byte sectors to be able to create partition/device-hosted hidden volumes up to 16 TB in size.

I'm new to Veracrypt and Linux. If I understood it correctly, to have an 8tb hidden partition I need to format the drive so that it'll have *"4096-byte sectors"*. I'm not finding this option in GParted.

Hence, my question is: *How can I in Linux Mint format the drive to have 4096-byte sectors, in order for me to install a Hidden Veracrypt partition?*

---

Steps taken to reproduce the problem:

1. Launch Veracrypt and choose "Create a volume within a
   partition/drive"
2. In "Volume Type" choose "Hidden Veracrypt Volume"
3. When in "Outer Volume Format", click format. Thus the error message I quoted will be displayed

I'm using the latest version of Veracrypt and Linux Mint

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072621/how-to-change-hard-disk-sector-size